# Pass object value to controller using Ajax GET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Course/GetChapters/",
        type: "GET",
        data:{id:2},
        beforeSend: function () { },
        success: function (result) {}
    })
    .done(function () {});
```

---

Can i pass a complex object via data?

Comment: reference the object in data? What is your issue? Did you try to set data to your object? What happened?

Comment: you can't pass functions but you can pass complex data structures. one way to do so is to just json encode it and pass it as a string then decode it on the server.

Comment: assuming the string is less chars than GET can handle, which isn't unlimited..

Comment: as complex as `JSON.stringify()` can encode (for POST)

Comment: If you want to send complex object you should think about using "POST" instead of "GET" :-)

Comment: Ok, but i can pass more than one value? I want to pass them to my action in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [JQuery Ajax - Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
>
> **Data** -> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

So as long as you have simple name/value pairs it should work. Of course the length of the URL is limited to 2,083 characters.

Comment: It's like query string. Ok thanks, do you have some example?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
var data = 'param1=' + value+ '&param2=' + value;
OR
var data = '{param1:'val1',param2:'val2',}'.